# Is SMTP plugin important for WordPress?

Tags: email, wordpress, smtp

I have a website based on WordPress.
Every page has his own Contact form.

I am using [Configure SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/configure-smtp/)
 + [Contact7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)
(SMTP is setup to user Gmail as a SMTP server).

After a while I'm curious why I am actually doing it this way. 
Is Gmail that secure or it is only about SSL? 
Is WP build in mail function secure (and good) enough to use it?

In total: what is the best way to make contact form in WordPress and avoiding my mails getting to the spam folder?

I was told that the solution descriped above (Gmail SMTP) is the best way, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the build-in mail function works fine for most uses, like sending "Password lost" or "New user registered" mails or even contact forms.

If you send more than just a few (can´t name a number) mails via contact forms, newsletters etc. you will probably want to use a mailserver for that, either an external one (GMail) or a properly configured internal one. They go much easier past spam protection because they are known for sending mails and are probably whitelisted at the big mail providers. Your webhost most probably is not and might be considered as spam very fast when he is sending mails regularly.

If you want to send a lot of mails in a short span of time you should probably go one step further and choose a service like [Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) or something similar for that. Their business is sending newsletters and so nobody (means the mail providers) wonders, when they have lots of mails incoming from one of those servers.

For your use case I would stick to SMTP via GMail, when it works fine for you. As you are not sending lots of mails in a short span of time you´ll have only little problems with getting rated as spam and you also have a trusted server sending those mails. Seems fine for me.